# Is it okay to use the past simple tense to describe continuous action in a chapter's opening sentence?

Tags: tenses

Consider:

CHAPTER 7.

> 1. Reclining on the couch, Sofonisba WAS STUFFING her face with Horatius’
>    omelet, chasing it down with tomato juice and occasionally adjusting
>    her unbrushed dyed hair.

OR:

> 2. Reclining on the couch, Sofonisba STUFFED her face with Horatius’ omelet, chasing it down with tomato juice and occasionally adjusting
>    her unbrushed dyed hair.

Answer (score 0):

The simple past generally means an action performed one time and then completed. The past continuous means continual action over a period of time.

So in this case, "stuffed her face" would be incorrect. It would indicate she did it once and then stopped, not that she carried on doing it for a period of time.

And yes, the distinction can be debatable. If I read, "George built a house", I assume that was a process requiring many months, possibly years.

Comment: How about this (another opening sentence): "A tall man with light-brown hair, wearing a summer suit without a tie and a pair of soft shoes, sat fastened to a chair, his mouth sealed with duct tape." Sat or was sitting?

Comment: Either. The past tense _sat_ can imply either _sat down_ (action) or _was sitting_ (state) - the context makes it clear which meaning is intended.